# How to make a Map with default values if key is not present?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, kotlin

I want to build a map of array parsing a list of object.
When a index of that map as already been added, i need to add the elements of the array that were not added before, else i need to create the new element in the Map.

Let's say we have a csv with data like this

```
names,nicknames
Tom,tommy;timmy
Sam,sammy
Tom,timmy;mymen
```

And i want a map like this :

```
Map["Tom"] = ["tommy", "timmy", "mymen"]
Map["Sam"] = ["sammy"]
```

I'm quite surprised that there is no native function for that

What's working, but should be improved ? (i have a 400k lines CSV to parse)

```
    val myObjectList: List<myObject> = beans.parse() /* importing POJOs from csv*/
    val myMap: MutableMap<String,List<String>> = mutableMapOf()

    myObjectList.forEach { entry ->
       if ( myMap[entry.name].isNullOrEmpty()) {
           myMap[entry.name] = entry.nicknames.split(";")
       } else {
           myMap[entry.name]!!.plus(entry.nicknames.split(";"))
       }
    }


    return myMap
```

Comment: There's no native support, I don't think there will be either. https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/the-standard-library-and-a-kotlin-manifesto/1303 Can't you use guava `MultiMap`?

Comment: MutliMap seems exactly what i need but I avoid adding dependencies to my project when not vital. I'll stick to my poor implementation :) Thanks anyway for your reply !

Comment: I have put an answer down, but I just wanted to clarify that the issue you are wanting a solution to is "How to make a Map with default values if key is not present?" and not a way to effeciently read a 400k line csv?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getOrPut` like:

```
data class MyObject(
        val name: String,
        val nicknames: String
)

fun main() {
    val myObjectList = listOf(
            MyObject("primary", "secondary1;secondary2"),
            MyObject("primary", "secondary3")
    )
    val nameToNicks = mutableMapOf<String, MutableList<String>>()

    myObjectList.forEach { myObj ->
        nameToNicks.getOrPut(myObj.name, {mutableListOf()}) .addAll(myObj.nicknames.split(";"))
    }

    print(nameToNicks)
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Did the trick ! I can't figure how it works because in documentation it's said that if a value is already stored, then the subsequent calls have no effect ?

Comment: Ya, so it will only build the default value once is what it is trying to say I think. So if you set it back to null, it won't work.